# Create method problem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that involves users, essays, and rankings. It's pretty straightforward but I'm very new to rails. The part I'm having trouble with right now is the create method for the rankings.

The Essay class `has_many :rankings` and the Ranking class `belongs_to :essay`

in the rankings controller I have:

```
def create
   @ranking = @essay.rankings.build(params[:ranking])
   flash[:success] = "Ranking created!"
   redirect_to root_path
end
```

but I get the error: undefined method `rankings' for nil:NilClass

I need each ranking to have an `essay_id`, and I believe `build` updates this for me.

I thought that rails give me the rankings method because of the relation I set, and why is `@essay` nil?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is @essay object??? Error is shouting... "undefined method `rankings' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build doesn't save. You should be using `new` and then `save`. I'd provide you sample code, but you haven't really given us a clear picture of what you have going on. That `@essay` instance variable is being used before it's defined, and I'm not really sure how your application is determining which essay the ranking belongs to.

You might wanna give [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) a read.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you intend to do:

```
# EssayController#new
def new
  @essay = Essay.new(params[:essay])
  @ranking = @essay.rankings.build(params[:ranking])
  #...
 end
```

Take a look at [nested model forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) , it should get you in the right direction.

Comment: I believe the context of this method is his RankingsController. He appears to want to create a new Ranking that belongs to an existing Essay. That said, your code suffers from the same problem as the original: `build` doesn't save.

Comment: That's true, I realized that after re-reading his question. Will edit for clarification.

Comment: Your edited solution seems to miss the boat again. He's trying to create Rankings that belong to **an existing Essay**.